# Belongs on another SE site

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic, stackexchange

When you click close, off-topic, belongs on another SE site, there are a few common options.  I believe iPhone/iOS (thinkdifferent.stackexchange.com) should be on the list.  Ideally, one should be able to scroll through the entire list...

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: You mean [apple.SE]?

Comment: Note that this feature request is a little dated and our current view on this is to keep it off the list to prevent on-topic Apple questions (Macs and OS X) from being migrated away.